# Can API response data be extracted according to the custom Type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I get the following data as a response result,

```
const response =  {
  name : “worr”,
  age : 34,
  id : “ttot”
  address : “earth”,
  postCode : 1432
}
```

I want to extract and receive only custom type data. Is there any way?

This is the custom type I want to extract.

```
Interface customerInfo {
   name : string,
   age : number
}
```

Comment: Why do you care about the excess data if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: I have to use an API that sends all uncategorized data, and I want to classify the data into a type suitable for each type in the front end.

Comment: No way! You need to make your own function to extract the desirable data.